# How to I implement this collision detection properly between two circle objects in python

Tags: python, graphics, collision-detection

This is a rudimentary windowed game in which a player controlled object circle must collect and eat bugs. I am struggling to get collision detection to work. When testing the game, the frog object passes through the bug without undrawing the bug and increasing score. Can anyone help me to see what I am missing?

```
from graphics import *
import random
import time

def getDirection(win: GraphWin, currentDirection):
    key = win.checkKey().lower()
    if key == "up":
        return "N"
    elif key == "down":
        return "S"
    elif key == "right":
        return "E"
    elif key == "left":
        return "W"
    else:
        return None

class Frog(object):
    """Frog based on circle object"""
    def __init__(self, x, y, size = 10, color = color_rgb(20, 200, 100), direction=None):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__direction = direction
        self.body = Circle(Point(self.__x, self.__y), 15)
        self.color = color
        self.__size = size
        self.alive = True

    def getX(self):
        return self.__x

    def getY(self):
        return self.__y

    def getSize(self):
        return self.__size

    def draw(self, win: GraphWin):
        """draws round green frog"""
        self.body.setFill(self.color)
        self.body.draw(win)

    def getDirection(self):
        return self.__direction

    def move(self, direction):
        self.__direction = direction

        if self.__direction == "N":
            self.body.move(0, -1 * self.__size)
            self.__y -= self.__size
        elif self.__direction == "S":
            self.body.move(0, self.__size)
            self.__y += self.__size
        elif self.__direction == "W":
            self.body.move(-1 * self.__size, 0)
            self.__x -= self.__size
        elif self.__direction == "E":
            self.body.move(self.__size, 0)
            self.__x += self.__size


class Bug(object):
    """smaller circle to rep bug"""
    score = 0

    def __init__(self, win:GraphWin, color = color_rgb(0, 0, 0)):
        self.__x = random.randrange(0, win.getWidth() - 20, 20)
        self.__y = random.randrange(0, win.getHeight() - 20, 20)
        self.__direction = None
        self.bug = Circle(Point(self.__x, self.__y), 5)
        self.color = color
        self.__size = 20

    def getX(self):
        return self.__x

    def getY(self):
        return self.__y

    def drawBug(self, win: GraphWin):
        self.bug.setFill(self.color)
        self.bug.draw(win)

    def detectCollision(self, frog):
        distance = ((self.__x - frog.getX()) ** 2 + (self.__y - frog.getY()) ** 2) ** 0.5
        if distance <= self.__size + frog.getSize():
            return True
        return False


    def eaten(self, body: Frog, win: GraphWin):
        if self.detectCollision(body):
            Bug.score += 10
            newX = random.randrange(20, win.getWidth() - 20, 20)
            newY = random.randrange(20, win.getHeight() - 20, 20)
            self.__x = newX
            self.__y = newY
            self.bug.undraw()
            self.bug = Circle(Point(self.__x, self.__y), 5)
            self.bug.setFill(self.color)
            self.bug.draw(win)

def bugEaten(bug:Bug, frog:Frog):
    body = frog.body
    if bug.getX() == body.getX() and bug.getY() == body.getY():
        return True
    return False

def checkEaten(bug: Bug, frog: Frog, win: GraphWin):
    if bug.detectCollision(frog):
        bug.eaten(frog, win)
        bug.bug.undraw()
        print(Bug.score)

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Frog Hop", 700, 700)
    frog = Frog(350, 350)
    frog.draw(win)
    bug = Bug(win)
    bug.drawBug(win)

    while frog.alive:
        direction = getDirection(win, frog.getDirection())
        frog.move(direction)
        time.sleep(.05)

main()
```

Comment: You have `checkEaten()` and `bugEaten()` that never gets called anywhere. Since that is where the bug being removed and makes calls to `Bug` for the collision detection, you effectively never detect collision.